# Rails method affects every user in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first rails project. I am trying to code a form that allows me to toggle the 'admin' field for any user, when the logged in user is an admin.

I found out how to do this using @post and remote: => true while searching on stack overflow.

However it seems that clicking on the make admin link changes every user to an admin, and that the remove admin link removes everyone from the admin list. Not sure why it is doing that. Here is the code:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
            <%= gravatar_for user, size: 35 %>
            <%= link_to user.name, user %> 
            <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
                | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
                <% if user.admin? %>
                | <%= link_to "remove admin rights", @post, :method => user.toggle!(:admin), :remote => true, 
                    data: { confirm: "You sure?"}%>
                <% else %>
                | <%= link_to "make admin", @post, :method => user.toggle!(:admin), :remote => true,
                    data: { confirm: "You sure?"}%>
                <% end %>

            <% end %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's aren't being changed when you click anything, they're being changed when you display your view. This:

```
:method => user.toggle!(:admin)
```

will call `user.toggle!(:admin)` right there, it isn't attaching a `user.toggle!` call to the click like you think it does. The `:method` is supposed to indicate which HTTP method (GET, POST, DELETE, ...) is supposed to be used, not what clicking the link is supposed to do.

You need to create a controller method and route that will call `user.toggle!` and then add a `link_to` to that controller.